# Can connect to the remote SQL server, but connection string test fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, connection-string, remote-access

I have my application and SQL database on two different PCs in the same LAN.
I use Visual Studio 2017 community version.

**I can connect to the database through SQL Server Object Explorer, in VS17**, but when I try to make a new connection string in my application setting using the same credentials, testing the connection fails.

Here is my connection string:

```
Data Source="192.168.1.194, 4135";Initial Catalog=Test_DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=remote_user;Password=1234
```

Any idea of how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: See SQL Server error log for the details of "login failed"

Comment: What are the errors in the SQL Server logs?

Comment: Port in window is 49173, port in string is 4135, which is it?

Comment: @mxmissile sorry! my mistake in posting the picture, (i'm not sure how to edit my question!) but port number and database names are the same in the window and connection string.

Comment: are there separate instances of sql server, or both PCs connect to the same instance?

Comment: @Jeremy yes, there are.

Comment: @Afshin you edit your question by clicking the button that says [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48428003/edit) at the bottom, to the left of your name on the question.

Comment: are both sql instances configured to accept remote connections?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying different ways, I finally made two other logins on the remote SQL Server, and interestingly those logins worked fine with my connection string. I suspect I could not use the same login on both SQL Server Object Explorer and the connection strings at the same time... just guessing... anyhow, it works fine for other logins.

Comment: Are you stating this is your answer, or is this further detail that other logins work? If the latter, consider editting your question. Those log entries would be really useful then as well.

Comment: @Larnu it solved my problem, so I consider it as the answer. Regarding the logs, I am not sure where they are located. I don't use SSMS, and the connection that I was trying to make was through visual studio.